# How to assign the @State value to another viewModel published property

Tags: swiftui

> How to assign the  @State value secondMarked from one view to a  @Published sampleViewModel property? like
> sampleViewModel.secondMarked

Here is the example:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sampleViewModel: sampleViewModel
            @State var firstMarked = false
            @State var secondMarked = true 
            @State var thirdMarked = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CheckboxField(id: "Completed", label: "Completed", isMarked: $firstMarked)
            CheckboxField(id: "Completed", label: "Completed", isMarked: $secondMarked)
            CheckboxField(id: "Completed", label: "Completed", isMarked: $thirdMarked)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do that with use of `.onChange` modifier, like

```
CheckboxField(id: "Completed", label: "Completed", isMarked: $secondMarked)
  .onChange(of: secondMarked) {
     sampleViewModel.secondMarked = $0     // << here !!
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having `@State` and a `@Published` property for it, just use one.

For example, yours:

```
CheckboxField(id: "Completed", label: "Completed", isMarked: $firstMarked)
```

Try this:

```
CheckboxField(id: "Completed", label: "Completed", isMarked: $sampleViewModel.firstMarked)
```