# SwiftUI: Change view @State property from ViewModel

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have date picker in my view like this:

```
struct BookTimeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: BookTimeViewModel

    @State var startTime = Date.now
    
 
     var body: some View {
         DatePicker(“pick time”, selection: $startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
     }
}
```

initial startTime depends on data from backend.

So in view model I have API call that loads data from backend.

In success callback I want to change startTime.

**Question: How can I change startTime from my ViewModel ?**

P.S.: Is that possible to bind DatePicker with ViewModel directly ?

I tried to put `@State var startTime = Date.now` in view model.
But it doesn't work, and I see warning in Xcode:

```
Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.
```

Comment: Why don't you want to bind `DatePicker` directly to `viewModel`?

Comment: @Asperi When I place State property in ViewModel, I see next warning:
ccessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.

Comment: Have it use the and `@Published`  that you api updates

Comment: I'm about binding to published property, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60058909/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi Wow. That it what I was looking for. Thanks man !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly bind to the `@Published` property with just:

```
$viewModel.startTime
```

Which will be of type `Binding<Date>`, even though we declare it as just a `@Published` property on `BookTimeViewModel`.

Example code:

```
class BookTimeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var startTime: Date = .now
}
```

```
struct BookTimeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: BookTimeViewModel

    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("pick time", selection: $viewModel.startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
    }
}
```

Similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971228/9607863).

Comment: How to assign Date object to  startTime: Binding<Date> ?

Comment: @Jim To assign, you can just do `viewModel.startTime = Date.now` for example. The code above is to create a `Binding` of it for your `DatePicker`.

Comment: When I try to assign Date.now to startTime: Binding<Date> I got error message that it's not possible to assign Date to Binding<Date>

Comment: @Jim You want `startTime` in `BookTimeViewModel` to be declared as `@Published var startTime = Date.now`. Then you can do the `viewModel.startTime = Date.now` as mentioned above, and also remove the `@State` variable for it. Remember to remove the `$` when just setting a new value.

Comment: The problem is that DatePicker works only with Binding<Date>. So I can't use just Publisher. It should be State or Binding<Date>

Comment: @Jim I think you may be slightly misunderstanding, so I've added example code.

Comment: Oh man. I tried to use $ before startTime, not before viewModel. Thank you !!! Your solution is simple and it works !!